# Raw input port 80

Tags: php, input

I tried tons of code to perform this task. I have some unformatted input to my server port 80, and I need to log this to file. How can I do this?

Comment: is `write(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));` sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Check this code, I used this to get raw input from POST requests, $var will store the input as it is, then you are free to do anything with it

```
ob_start();
readfile("php://input");
$var = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not going to give you access to the raw input. The closest you will get to the data is with `php://input` or `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` but those only give access to the HTTP body (after the headers). Additionally, your "unformatted" input would cause a parse error on the web server before PHP even gets a chance to process it.

If you really need to log all traffic, that may not even be proper HTTP, you need to look to features of your firewall or web server instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to log something to a file, you shouldn't use web programming languages.. Use C++ or C# instead and monitor the port and log the stream in a file..